# Confirm box with jQuery

Tags: jquery, confirm

When i normally use a confirm box for a link i do it this way:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Wollen Sie den Datensatz wirklich löschen?')">Delete</button>
```

Now i have to submit a form. In the message of the confirm box the value of an input field of the form has to be shown.

My attempt to solve this was:

```
<input id="endetzum" type="text" class="form-control" name="Kursende" form="formularmodal3">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Auswählen" form="formularmodal3" id="buttonkursende">

$('#buttonkursende').click(function(){
var datumende = ($("#endetzum").val());
confirm('Der Kurs endet zum '+datumende);
});
```

It also works optically, but the form is always executed regardless of whether "ok" or "cancel" is clicked.

How can I prevent the form from being sent when "cancel" is clicked?

Comment: You would need to return the `confirm` dialog's result

Comment: Maybe this helps you. Did you have a type="button" in your html code for the cancel button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid further execution with jQuery event binding, either the event function has to return `false` or the `event.preventDefault()` can be used

```js
$('#buttonkursende').click(function(){
    var datumende = ($("#endetzum").val());
    return confirm('Der Kurs endet zum '+datumende);
});

// or

$('#buttonkursende').click(function(e){
    var datumende = ($("#endetzum").val());
    if(!confirm('Der Kurs endet zum '+datumende)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh that was easy, with the "return" it work fine. :- ) 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

to solve this issue use `.submit()` event to handle this form submission code.

try below code it  will work for you.

before using the below code please make sure formularmodal3 is the id of your form.

```
$('#formularmodal3').submit(function(){
    var datumende = ($("#endetzum").val());
    var result =    confirm('Der Kurs endet zum '+datumende);
    return result;
});
```

Comment: Worth noting that returning false on the button click effectively does the same. Agree that using submit event makes more sense though